# Relational data model to NoSQL, Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, consistency, nosql

We are about to start a new project and one of the **requirements** is to use NoSQL solution. 90% chance that it will be Amazon DynamoDB since we are 'aws dependent'. We are looking into TitanDB (graph) on top of DynamoDB storage.

**Data model consists of:**

- User roles, permissions, token storage
- More relational like data with one to many / one to one associations

**Task we are going to solve:**

- Build reports on top of the data. Some reports can include fields from different entities
- Filter by range (from - to)
- Sorting, count, pagination
- All of the above can be applied at the same time

**Volume of the data:**

- Amount of data is not so large, we are not streaming events in realtime

**Assumptions:**
As I understand we'll need to create denormalized views for the reports we are going to build (merge data from different 'tables') - keep copies of the data in several tables.
Or
We need to use Elasticsearch or another solution for indexing.

Graph db experience looks crazy but provides a clear data model where each entity has relation to another. Need to know limitations of db api for queries.

**Questions:**

- What are the best ways to manage relational data in non relational db and keep it consistent?
- Are there any transaction support (in DynamoDB e.g.) to keep the data consistent (during data updates we should write to several tables because of denormalization)?
- Is it a good solution to integrate with Elasticsearch and make search requests to it and then grab the data by ids from DB?

Answer (score 0):

TitanDB on Dynamo is a supported Amazon Web Services solution, documented at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.html

For reporting and other interactions, you'll use Apache Tikerpop ( http://tinkerpop.apache.org ), which doesn't include a 'reporting engine' or a JDBC connector, but it does provide connectors to many languages that can easily be used to construct reports: python, scala, go, .NET/C#, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Read consistency in DynamoDB can be eventually consistent or strongly consistent; take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html for details about the differences between the two.

Using ElasticSearch with graph is still an emerging technology combination. There are some projects out there (elastic-gremlin and unipop) that are addressing it. Depending on your use case, you should be able to get the data by traversing  the Titan graph with Gremlin (which is part of Tinkerpop) without adding an additional layer of ElasticSearch ... but you might not. If you want an easy way to experiment with an ES environment in AWS, you might want to look at https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/

Also: if you have an AWS support contract you should reach out to them - it's not just for break/fix. The support team can connect you to AWS technical people who can help validate and even test your plans.